# ADOdb support in PhpStorm 2017.1

Tags: php, database, adodb-php

I have to manage with PhpStorm 2017.1 a large PHP project built on top of ADOdb library. Unfortunately the IDE does not provide any support for this library: for every method I use, I get a "Method not found" warning (and obviously there's no parameter hint, ça va sans dire).

I see there's an OLD thread (~2011) about this, and after that nothing more, maybe ADOdb is kinda Area51 secret none can talk about. Or maybe it's just an old tech none is interested in.

By the way: is there any way (a plugin, a command, a something) that can make my PhpStorm able to understsand ADOdb?

Answer (score 1):

PHPstorm won't likely recognize many of the commands in the library because of the way the ADOdb classes are instantiated. The design of ADOdb is quite old, but in no way is the code secret, or abandoned. You will find it fully documented at [The ADOdb project site](http://adodb.org)

Answer (score 0):

ADOdb is a pure-PHP library (as opposed to a binary extension), so if you have the ADOdb PHP files in a subdirectory in your project it should "just work" because PHPStorm will parse those PHP files as though they were your own files, and so derive information about the functions and classes contained within - just like any other PHP library.

Comment: it should but it won't. my code starts with a
include_once "lib/adodb/adodb.inc.php";
but it is not enough... any suggestion?

Comment: edit: the library is working, and in PhpStorm I can see SOME of the functions/methods/etc., but methods like Execute or RecordCount are unrecognized...